# Single value showing when multiple should be showing - php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am working a php script that for some reason will not allow me to print out related information into the same column of a csv. What I first do is query the database to build a basic user profile, then fill information of that user based on a unique id. What I then wanted to to do was retrieve scores associated with that user and post them into a column with that particular user defining what row the information would reveal. However my efforts have got me as far as producing a single score for each user despite the fact that they have many scores associated with them. I have placed the code below:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($answers, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    if ($last_uniq_id != $row[0]) {
        $i++;
        $k=2;

        $last_uniq_id = $row[0];
    }

    $myarray[$i][0] = $row[0];
    $myarray[$i][1] = $row[1];
    $myarray[$i][$k] = str_replace('"', '""', $row[3]);

    $k++;

    if ($k == $length) {
        $first_speaker=1;
        // Get all speakers
        $query = "SELECT * FROM v_events_abstracts_speakers WHERE abstract_id='".$row[0] ."' ORDER BY speaker_id ASC";

        $result_speakers = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        $num_speakers = mysql_num_rows($result_speakers);


        while ($row_sp = mysql_fetch_array($result_speakers, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            if ($first_speaker==1) {
                $myarray[$i][$length] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[first_name]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 1] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[last_name]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 2] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[title]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 3] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[organization]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 4] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[phone]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 5] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[email]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 6] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[xperience_level]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 7] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[bio]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 8] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[url]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 9] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[status]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 10] = $row[4];
                $myarray[$i][$length + 11] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[twitter]);               
                $first_speaker=2;
            } else {
                $i++;
                for ($m = 0; $m < $length; $m ++) {
                    $myarray[$i][$m] = "";
                }               
                $myarray[$i][0] = $row[0];
                $myarray[$i][1] = $row[1];
                $myarray[$i][$length] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[first_name]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 1] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[last_name]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 2] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[title]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 3] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[organization]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 4] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[phone]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 5] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[email]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 6] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[experience_level]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 7] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[bio]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 8] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[url]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 9] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[status]);
                $myarray[$i][$length + 10] = $row[4];
                $myarray[$i][$length + 11] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $row_sp[twitter]);                   
            }
        }

    **// Get Evaluation Form Questions
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM v_events_abstracts_votes WHERE abstract_id='.$row['uniq_id'];
    $arrQuestions = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $last_vote_id="";
    $last_abstract_id = $row['uniq_id'];

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($arrQuestions)){
        if($last_abstract_id == $rows['abstract_id']):
        $myarray[$i][$length + 12] = $rows['vote_result'];
    else:
        $last_abstract_id == $rows['abstract_id'];
    endif;

    }**


    }



}
```

The first part of the code builds the user profile by filling in preset columns. The part I am having an issue with is denoted by the **. What I was think was set the last_value an initial value of $row['uniq_id']. From there enter the while loop. If the last_value equals a user's id (which in this case i called abstract id -- i know terrible name) then print out the column. if not then set it to the current user and do the process over again. However like I said this only produces one score per user.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: NOTE: You should use mysqli functions

Comment: I know. This is an old piece of code the client does not want me to spend the time updating. I use real_escape_string before putting anything into the db